# WebDriverWait. Fast check element exist or not exist

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I got a problem and I don't know how to solve it right. Situation: user enters login and password, and then he could be at one of two pages. 
Question is: how to check correctly in which page we are?

**1**. I want to use WebDriverWait, so my implicitlyWait = 0 ms,

**2**. I use Page Object pattern, pages were initialized with AjaxElementLocatorFactory

**a**. So, if I'll do method for check some element like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "pushOutMessage")
private WebElement messageText;

public boolean pageIsPresent() {
    return messageText.isDisplayed();
}
```

It will be not right because if page is wrong, then WebDriver will wait N seconds for this element. So it makes my simple tests slow, very-very slow.

**b**. If I will check element with "findElement" - my implicity waits is 0 ms, so if element was slowly-loaded pageIsPresent returns false, even if page is right.

I hope there is some other way to do this. Need your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do that. but the easiest way will be to check the elemenet counts

I would rather do

```
@FindBy(id = "pushOutMessage")
private List<WebElement> elements;

public int pageIsPresent() {
    return elements.size();
}
```

And, somewhere test the pageIsPresent() is 0 or greater. if greater than *0* we know the page element was returned

And, since you are using pageobject pattern and `Java` I would recommand you to create an overloading to the baseClass which will check for a selector everytime you instantiate a new pageobject. I have a git repo [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG/tree/master/src/PageObjects) with TestNG. that might help

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have tried to check size of element's list, but the problem is still there - if element is not exist, driver waiting for it for a long time.

Comment: @Pasha That wait might be happening for some other reason. There is no wait we are using in above codes.

Answer (score 0):

After the user enters or clicks submit or login button you can do something like this:

```
public Object clickLogin() {
    loginElement.click();
    try{
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementedLocatedBy(By.id("pushOutMessage")));
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, FirstPage.class);
    } catch (TimeoutException te) {
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, SecondPage.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, as I understand it, the idea is to use another WebDriverWait with shorter (1-3 seconds) timeout?

Comment: yup u can do that...but if u r confident that it would reflect within that timespan.